# GGTS - SVN check out never complete

Tags: eclipse, svn, grails, tortoisesvn, subversive

I am using GGTS (64 bit) for a small Grails project.
I created SVN repository on Google drive using TortoiseSVN and checked-in the project.

On second computer, I tried to check-out the project but it seems that GGTS cannot complete the checkout.

I can see the "Check out" task is stack in 98%, I can see all files in the newly created project in the workspace, but the task never ends.
I can also see other tasks running:

- Refresh DSLD scripts
- Refresh external folders
- Decoration calculation
- Resources changed

Using latest Subversive with SVNKit 1.8 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. What's the point of storing Subversion repository in Google Drive? [Don't do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978987/svn-repository-on-google-drive-or-dropbox)
2. Can you reproduce this using a command-line client?