# TortoiseSVN: Using Google Drive direct host link?

Tags: svn, google-drive-api, repository, tortoisesvn

I'm able to use Tortoise SVN to view repositories on Google Drive, if I have google drive client installed, and the repository is synced to the Google Drive folder. I'd like to make it easier and take up less storage space if I could simply access the repository with an https link directly. I've been able to do this over at riouxsvn.com, but cannot with Google Drive. I've found out that I can get a direct link to a folder if I use *https://googledrive.com/host/[FolderID]* , and I did get that folder ID. I'm able to paste that into a new tab, and that works. But when I try to connect to that URL with Tortoise SVN's repository browser, it will not cooperate.

So I need to find out how to make it successfully connect to the google drive folder with the link. I do have the repository set up. In the browser, I get two errors, essentially. One is that it cannot connect, and the second being it cannot open the repository (obviously, since it can't connect).

Much help appreciated. THanks.

**EDIT**

After the page was loaded in a chrome tab, the URL is changed, and I get something like this:
https://298rjg498tj358gj.googledrive.com/host/sadf85jf9348jf
(not working link, just example)
It is different than the one I tried to use. When I put this into the tortoise browser, I get this:

`The XML response contains invalid XML`

`Malformed XML: no element found`

Is there something I can add to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVN Repository on Google Drive or DropBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978987/svn-repository-on-google-drive-or-dropbox)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, and you're fortunate that keeping your repository on Google Drive hasn't corrupted the repository.

To serve a repository via HTTP, you must have the Subversion server libraries running on the server. Google Drive does not provide this (nor can you coerce it to do so).

For more detail see [SVN Repository on Google Drive or DropBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12978987/1324345)